# codeblocks debugging

Tags: debugging, codeblocks

For some reason I can no longer debug in codeblocks. Breakpoints are ignored and exceptions are not caught. I'm pretty sure it was working before on this machine, but I have to confess that since I work on multiple machines I might be confused on that matter.

I'm running Kubuntu 11.04 and codeblocks 10.05. Under Build Options "Produce debugging symbols [-g]" is checked (for both debug and release builds) and "Strip all symbols from binary" is not checked. But every time I run the debugger I get the message "(no debugging symbols found)" which I suspect is at the heart of the problem.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Be sure that you have consistent settings regarding "produce debug symbols" and "strip". You can set those a) globally b) for the project c) for the build target. If you have accidentially set _one_ of them to strip, it will strip anyway (and you get just what you have -- no symbols). It's easy to accidentially switch from target to project in the tree view inside the settings dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. All was well, but just to be sure I set project, debug, and release (project - build options) to be exactly the same: Produce debugging symbols is checked and nothing else is. Still no luck. Where are the global settings you refer to. Maybe that's the ticket?!

Comment: Got it! Found the global setting you referred to in Settings - compiler and debugger. I had set -s a few days ago and there it still was. Now all is well. Thank you very much for your help! It's quite a relief.  :)

Answer (score 2):

At middle 2013 i was using Codeblocks 10.05 with GDB 7.5.1 in Debian Wheezy (7.0), and faced the same problem, breakpoints ignored and when and exception was thrown (even if it was caught) the process stops working.

Suspecting of a GDB bug I downloaded the GDB version 7.6 sources and compiled it. The same behaviour was observed.

Finaly I downloaded the CodeBlocks version 12.11, and that fixed the problem. It seems that the CodeBlocks version 10.05 was the key of the problem.