# Codeblocks "Error resetting breakpoint..." can't debug

Tags: debugging, codeblocks

This is my first post, so feel free to direct me elsewhere if this is in the wrong place.  I'm totally new to code::blocks, and I followed the directions (twice) from [here](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,3232.0.html) to set it up with minGW.  Other than some expected warnings, it builds just fine.  However, when I go to debug it, I get the following messages:

```
Setting breakpoints Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4 
Child process PID: 3928 [Inferior 1 (process 3928) exited with code
[037777777777] Debugger finished with status 0
```

When I set a breakpoint, I get the following:

```
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4
Child process PID: 3092
Error in re-setting breakpoint 2: Function "C:/Users/Me/Documents/My Code/MyProgram/MyProgram/main.cpp:5" not defined.
[Inferior 1 (process 3092) exited with code 037777777777]
Debugger finished with status 0
```

I have searched and searched, but I haven't found anything.  The only relevant posts on this site,
[CodeBlocks Breakpoints Ignoring Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730453/codeblocks-breakpoints-ignoring-scope)
[codeblocks debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549607/codeblocks-debugging)
[How to debug in Codeblocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041614/how-to-debug-in-codeblocks),
have not helped me at all.  I've reinstalled everything twice and I have no idea what else to do to get this debugger working.  Any help at all would be appreciated.

EDIT:  I made "Hello World!" and it ran, but still could not be debugged.  No idea what the problem is, especially since it detects gdb.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if there is a space in your build path (in your case "My Code").
Just rename that directory or move the project to a place where there are no spaces in your path.

Reason:
Ref this link: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code::Blocks#Path_with_spaces

You may have to clean and build your project again

Comment: had the same problem with cdb - removing space from path helped. A LOT :)