# debug doesn't stop at breakpoint in codeblock

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

I'm using codeblock to test two projects. In one project everything is right, I can both run and debug the code. However in another project I can only run the code but could not debug. I set up breakpoint and begin debug, but it doesn't stop at the breakpoint. Could anyone tell me what might be wrong here?

I searched and find this thread [Codeblocks "Error resetting breakpoint..." can't debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756301/codeblocks-error-resetting-breakpoint-cant-debug)
and I've make sure there is no space in my project file names.

The following is from the Debugger

```
Starting debugger: C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MINGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname  -quiet  -args D:/SOFTWA~1/C__~1/LEARNC~1/SELECT~1/bin/Debug/SELECT~1.EXE
done
Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
(no debugging symbols found)
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb 6.8
Child process PID: 12992
(no debugging symbols found)
(no debugging symbols found)
(no debugging symbols found)
(no debugging symbols found)
(no debugging symbols found)
Program exited normally.
Debugger finished with status 0
```

Comment: Use the GBD console and issue the "inf b" command. When a breakpoint is "pending" the reason is usually shown in the console.

Comment: Hi harper, could you tell me how to get to GBD console? I'm not sure how to do it. thanks!

Comment: `(no debugging symbols found)`. Isn't that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

no debugging symbols found,it tells you that you should add -g option when you compile the project.